# to calculate the angle of an object and cosine value

Tags: java

> I need to calculate the value of cosine theta and 
>   Also i need to finally find the value of angle between the current position of the robot and the new position it moved. The theta value.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import mrds_project.Path;
import mrds_project.Pose;
import mrds_project.controller.Controller;
import java.lang.Math;

public class NaiveStrategy implements PathStrategy {

private final Controller controller;

private NaiveStrategy() {

}
public NaiveStrategy(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void move(Path path) {
    for (Pose target : path) {
                    Pose currentPose = controller.getPose();
        double[] targetPoint = target.getPosition().getVector();
                    double targetVectorX;
                    double targetVectorY;
                    double currentVector;
                    targetVectorX = targetPoint[0] - currentPose.getPosition().getVector()[0];
                    targetVectorY = targetPoint[1] - currentPose.getPosition().getVector()[1];
    }
}
    public double dotPro1(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB){
        double[] vecPro;
        vecPro = new double[2];
        vecPro[0] = vectorA[0]*vectorB[0];
        vecPro[1] = vectorA[1]*vectorB[1];
        return vecPro[0] + vecPro[1];
    }
    public double dotPro2(double[] length){
        double[] lenPro;
        lenPro = new double[1];
        lenPro[0] = length[0];
        return lenPro[0];
    }
    public static double cosine(double a) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
        Class c = Class.forName("NaiveStrategy");
        Class methodTypes[] = new Class[3];
        methodTypes[0] = Double.TYPE;
        methodTypes[1] = Double.TYPE;
        methodTypes[2] = Double.TYPE;
        Method[] m = c.getMethods();
        NaiveStrategy ns = new NaiveStrategy();
        Object arg[] = new Object[3];
        arg[0] = new Double(50);
        arg[1] = new Double(50);
        arg[2] = new Double(50);
        Object o = m.ns(ns, arg);
        return 0;  
    }
}
```

I need to know the answer for this, I am getting an error in constructor, i know why is it because of the "variable controller might not have initialized". And ERROR in the last line before the return statement, i have no idea, it says "cannot find symbol"

```
Controller.java
package mrds_project.controller;

import mrds_project.Pose;


public interface Controller {
void setVelocity(int linear, int angular);
public Pose getPose();

}
Pose.java
package mrds_project;

import java.util.Map;

public class Pose {
private final Quaternion orientation;
private final Quaternion position;

public Pose(Map<String, Object> mrdsmap)
{
Map<String, Object> orientationMap = (Map<String, Object>) mrdsmap.get("Orientation");
double w = (Double) orientationMap.get("W");
double x = (Double)orientationMap.get("X");
double y = (Double)orientationMap.get("Y");
double z = (Double)orientationMap.get("Z");
orientation = new Quaternion(w, x, y, z);
Map<String, Object> positionMap = (Map<String, Object>) mrdsmap.get("Position");
double x1 = (Double)positionMap.get("X");
double y1 = (Double)positionMap.get("Y");
double z1 = (Double)positionMap.get("Z");
position = new Quaternion(x1, y1, z1);
}


public Quaternion getOrientation() {
return orientation;
}

public Quaternion getPosition() {
return position;
}
}
```

Comment: You are doing some weird stuff here.  Why do you need to throw `IOException` *and* `ClassNotFoundException`?  There doesn't seem to be any IO in the method, and I'm not entirely sure why you would want to use a `Class` object there.

Comment: @Makoto, hmm can you suggest me what should i correct in my coding.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have an unassigned final variable

```
private final Controller controller;
```

*and* a default constructor - the compiler will guard against the variable not being assigned. Removing the `final` keyword will allow you to keep the 2 constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Object o = m.ns(ns, arg);
```

to

```
Object o = m.invoke(ns, arg);
```

But why are you using reflections anyway? Why not use

```
    public static double cosine(double a) {
        double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a));
        NaiveStrategy ns = new NaiveStrategy();
        ns.YourMethodHere(50, 50, 50);
        return 0;  
    }
```

Comment: Object o = m.invoke(ns, arg) it is not working.

Comment: Again, post the actual error message.

Comment: I've edited my post check it out.